# Calculate the area between $f(t) = \cos(t)$ and the $t$ axis as $t$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/4$

Tags: integration

The problem below is part of a multiple section question that I'm hoping to solve.

Calculate the area between $f(t) = \cos(t)$ and the $t$ axis as $t$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/4$.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I guess I need to find the roots and see what type of lines function it is. and then integrate the function and plug in the values

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: What are the roots for in this problem ? What is the definition of the area below the curve between "a" and "b" ?

Comment: There's no need to find any sort of roots. The important thing is to note that $\cos$ is continuous on $[0,\frac \pi 4]$, therefore integrable there. The area is then given by an appropiate integral.

Comment: I thinks first I need to determine whether the curve is above or bellow the x-axis but since it is not a function such as x2+x+c I can't figure it out

Comment: @CashVai $\cos$ lies above the $t$-axis in $[0, \frac \pi 4]$, but let's assume that $g$ is a function that is positive in $[0,\frac \pi 8[, g\left(\frac \pi 8\right)=0$ and negative in $]\frac \pi 8, \frac \pi 4]$. If by area between $g(t)$ and the $t$-axis you mean something like, in this [picture](http://figures.boundless.com/17884/raw/420px-integral-example.svg.png), $\text{blue}+\text{yellow}+\text{blue}$, then you need to beware of where $g$ lies, but if you mean $\text{blue}-\text{yellow}+\text{blue}$, then you can ignore the sign of $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Area}=\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos(t) \space\text{d}t=[\sin(t)]_0^{\pi/4}=\sin(\pi/4)-\sin(0)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-0=0.5\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: how do you write the equation in above (proper) form? I can't find the option

Comment: Use MathJax, basic tutorial and quick reference in meta here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference